# C++ adding string and int

Tags: c#, c++

I have been tasked to rewrite a small program written in C++ to C#.

But I came across this line that I couldn't understand fully. Is it concatenating the string length to the string or the pointer?

```
int n = _keyData * int(*(int*)(_chap + strlen(_chap) - 4));
```

This is the variables:

```
short _ver = 12;
short _keyData = short(_ver * _ver);
char _chap[100]; // Hold time with format [%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d:%03d]
```

Comment: It's doing some very low-level pointer manipulations on packed data. If you want to use a high-level language like C#, the best thing to do is to grab whatever `_chap` is at the endpoint and *immediately* parse it into a class or high-level data structure, so that this sort of trickery is not pervasive in your code base.

Comment: Looks like interpreting last 4 bytes of the string (not array) as an integer

Comment: Are you just asking what the C++ code does (in which case, see Alexey Larionov's comment), or do you also want to know how to do the same thing in C#?

Comment: @Petrusion yes i'm asking what the C++ code does

Comment: there is no concatenation, this code actually multiplying `_keydata` with an address casted to integer... this is pretty weird... anyway, no, it isn't string concatenation at all, it is numbers and arithemtic computing using pointer/reference address.

Comment: @Sedenion it is not casting an address to an int. It is dereferencing the address to read an int which is located at the address.

Comment: Something to note: `strlen(_chap)` only works if `_chap` is a null-terminated string, but the rest of the code implies that `_chap` contains binary data, which likely may contain 0x00 bytes in it, which will break `strlen()`. This whole code makes no sense. I wouldn't dare try to translate it to C# before fully understanding what it is actually trying to do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau indeed, it read the last 4 bytes of the the buffer, as an `int`...

Comment: @Sedenion I know that, but what I'm saying is that if such an `int` held any 0x00 bytes, they would prevent `strlen()` from calculating the correct string length to begin with. It doesn't make much sense to reinterpret a series of textual string characters as a binary integer. And if the string does happen to contain packed binary data, then `strlen()` is the wrong function to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*(int*)(_chap + strlen(_chap) - 4)` is a strict aliasing violation. Reinterpreting raw bytes as an `int` is type punning and is not allowed in C++ (even though some compilers tolerate it).

To fix it (assuming a little-endian system), you can rewrite it like this:

```
short _ver = 12;
short _keyData = short(_ver * _ver);
char _chap[100]; // Hold time with format [%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d:%03d]

int len = strlen(_chap);
int x = (int)(((unsigned)_chap[len - 1] << 24) |
              ((unsigned)_chap[len - 2] << 16) |
              ((unsigned)_chap[len - 3] <<  8) |
               (unsigned)_chap[len - 4]);
int n = _keyData * x;
```

Coincidently, it should be easy to port this to C# now.

Comment: Or to just use the native endianness, like the original code was written to do, (but failed because of strict aliasing violation), C++ can use `memcpy` and C# can use `BitConverter.ToInt32`